# How to find recurrence for $f(x)$ coefficient in the expression $f(x)\cdot(1+2x+2x^2+x^3)=\frac{1}{1-x^3}$ using generating functions?

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

> Let $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_ix^i$. Also $f(x)\cdot(1+2x+2x^2+x^3)=\frac{1}{1-x^3}$. Find numbers $b,c,d$ such that:
>   $$
> a_n={3+n-1 \choose n}-ba_{n-1}-ca_{n-2}-da_{n-3}
> $$
>   for $n\ge 3$.

The expression can be modified to the following using generating functions:
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x^3} : (1+2x+2x^2+x^3)=\frac{1}{1-x^3}:(1+x)(1+x+x^2)=\frac{(1-x)^2}{(1-x^3)^2(1-x^2)}
$$
Then: 
$$
f(n)=\sum_{n=0}^2 {2\choose n}(-1)^nx^n\cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2+n-1\choose n}x^{3n}\cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{2n}
$$
For example:
$$
a_0={2\choose 0}{1\choose 0}\cdot 1=1\\
a_1=-{2\choose 1}{2\choose 1}\cdot 1=-4\\
a_2={2\choose 2}{3\choose 2}\cdot 1=1
$$
but what happens with $\sum_{n=0}^2 {2\choose n}(-1)^nx^n$ for $a_n$ where $n\ge 3$? Its range for $n$ is only between $0$ and $2$ so does it become $1$ for all $n\ge 3$? If it does then:
$$
a_3 = {4\choose 3}\cdot 1=4
$$
Then:
$$
a_3={5\choose 3}-3b+4c-d=10-3b+4c+d=4\implies 3b-4c-d=6 \qquad \ast
$$
But there's an infinite amount of solutions for the above equation so I don't think I'm in the right direction.

---

**Note:** as noticed by @ancientmathematician there was a mistake in the conditions to the problem it should be $f(x)\cdot(1+2x+2x^2+x^3)=\frac{1}{(1-x)^3}$

Comment: Using Taylor series at $x=0$ for $f(x)\cdot(1+2x+2x^2+x^3)-\frac{1}{1-x^3}$, the coefficients I obtain are $\{1,-2,2,0,-2,2,1,-4,4,0,-4\}$

Comment: Are you sure that you've got the question right? Isn't it $\frac{1}{(1-x)^3}$

Comment: @ancientmathematician confirming that the fraction is correct. I will check with the course if maybe there's a mistake

Comment: There must be, the factorial arises from my version, yours would replace  the factorial by a period 3 $1,0,0$. (As @Ray shows in detail).

Comment: I now see the mistake in how I was calculating the coefficients from my formula. I should've only used $\sum_{n=0}^2 {2\choose n}(-1)^nx^n$ because only it can contribute to the coefficients $a_0,a_1,a_2$. But if I use this formula I get $a_0=1, a_1=-2, a_2=1$ instead of $a_2=2$ as shown in the answer and in @ClaudeLeibovici comment. Why is that?

Comment: and indeed there was a mistake in the conditions, I edited the OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe Claude is correct about the statement of the problem, but I will attempt to provide some useful commentary as is.

So if we substitute $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_{i}x^i$ in for $f(x)$, we obtain

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_{i}x^i + 2x\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_{i}x^i + 2x^2\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_{i}x^i + x^3\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_{i}x^i = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^{3i}$$

If you insert the $x$'s into the sums, and peel off all terms with degree $2$ or less, we obtain

$$a_0 + (2a_0+a_1)x + (2a_0 + 2a_1 + a_2)x^2 + \sum_{i=3}^{\infty} (a_{i}+ 2a_{i-1} + 2a_{i-2} + a_{i-3})x^i = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} x^{3i}$$

Equating coefficients, we can say

$$a_0 = 1$$
$$2a_0+a_1 = 0$$
$$2a_0 + 2a_1 + a_2 = 0$$
$$a_{i}+ 2a_{i-1} + 2a_{i-2} + a_{i-3} = 1, i\geq3$$

Where the last equation holds if $i$ divides $3$, and is $0$ otherwise.

The first three equations give initial values $a_0, a_1, a_2$, and the third statement leads me to believe Claude's comment, since that would yield the desired binomial coefficient in place of the $1$ in the recurrence relation. Hope this helps!

Edit: Notice

$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^3} = \sum_{n\geq 0} \dbinom{-3}{n}(-1)^nx^n = \sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{(-3)(-3-1)...(-3-n+1)}{n!}(-1)^nx^n$$
$$=\sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{(3)(4)...(3+n-1)}{n!}x^n =\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(2)(3)(4)...(3+n-1)}{(3-1)n!}x^n = \sum_{n\geq 0}\dbinom{3+n-1}{n}x^n$$

So if you were to have equated coefficients as above, you would get the desired recurrence relation.

Comment: how did you get this sum $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_{i}x^i + 2x\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_{i}x^i + 2x^2\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_{i}x^i + x^3\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_{i}x^i = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^{3i}$?

Comment: Sorry, I skipped a few steps, first distribute $f(x)$ over $1 + 2x + 2x^2 + 2x^3$, then substitute $f(x)$ with the generating function

Comment: but didn't I do this in the OP?

Comment: It looks like you divided $1 + 2x + 2x^2 + x^3$ from both sides and did some (very clever) algebra to make the expression a bit more tame. I'm suggesting that you forgo that and distribute $f(x)$ directly into $1 + x + 2x^2 + x^3$ on the left hand side

Comment: First of all thank you for the amazing answer! I'd like to clarify regarding the expression $\frac{1}{(1-x)^3}$ isn't it supposed to equal ${3+n-1\choose n}$?

Comment: Yes, my mistake, just fixed it!